# How to convert a char to a long without first making it an int?

Tags: java, integer

Char, int and long are all integers, but with other large of bits.

I know that if you create a long from an integer for example:

```
int a=39; long b=a;
```

that in the long is not a number with 64 bits, it is also a integer with 32 bits.

When we make:

```
int a=39; long b=aL;
```

I have read that if you add for example an L to the long, that then at the long is also a number with 64 bit. But I read that Java internally sees the integer before as an integer and by the L the number then becomes a 64 bit. But before that the number is also stored in the long as 32 bit for a short time.

So I have read that in general always first an integer with 32 bits is formed in long and then this is made to 64 bit. So even if someone makes long test =93L;, in the long first an integer with 32 bits is created, which is extended afterwards with the L and thereby becomes 64 bit. So as an intermediate step you always have an integer. Is that correct?

If yes, how can I convert a char for example  `char test1 ='A'` to a long without making them before to a 32bit integer? Because if I am right, if I make `long test2=test1;` there is no long/integer with 64 bits in the long, there is only one with 32 bits. Is that true?

Or is it that now in the long is an integer with 64 bits? If so was it 32 bits before for a short moment?

If what I say is true, how can I make a char directly 64 bits without it being an int for a short moment first?

Comment: I don't think this question belongs in Stack Overflow. For theoretical questions, you probably want to post it in Stack Exchange Computer Science or similar channel.

Comment: @hfontanez: this is in no way theoretical.

Comment: Okay but how I can know that, without to know the theoretical aspects about java?

Comment: Need to look at the generated intermediate code. But I don't know how.

Comment: @wdqoihj2 I would test your hypothesis first by making a small program that only does `long a = 'a';`, compile it, disassemble it and see if this business of "it's 32-bit for a short period" is actually true.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how is this in no way theoretical?

Comment: @hfontanez: there is no "theory of type conversion" and the question is about concrete implementations. It is a triviality.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There doesn't have to be a "theory of type conversion" for this to be a theoretical case. I think Federico's example kind of proved that. I don't remember, but I think you can do this in Assembly. Java does an intermediate step. C++ might not. While you see it as "concrete implementations" I see it as to why this implementation does that while other might not. I think that's at the root of the OPs question. At least, that's how I see it.

Comment: @hfontanez: no.

Comment: @YvesDaoust agree to disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try with a test program

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long a = 'a';
    }
}
```

Let's compile it

```
javac Test.java
```

Let's disassemble it

```
javap -c Test.class
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 97l
       3: lstore_1
       4: return
}
```

See this:

```
0: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 97l
```

It's loading 97 (the numerical value of `'a'`) directly as a `long`. There's no intermediate step in which your value is 32 bits wide.

If you don't do this directly, of course you get a different result, i.e. the number is stored as a 32-bits int first and then loaded into a long (but you're explicitly asking for that by declaring `a` as a `char`, so that's not surprising)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char a = 'a';
        long b = a;
    }
}
```

Let's decompile this

```
javap -c Test.class
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: bipush        97
       2: istore_1
       3: iload_1
       4: i2l
       5: lstore_2
       6: return
}
```

Comment: @wdqoihj2 if you do an intermediate step, yes. I'll amend my answer with that example.

Comment: Do you know a method to make it directly to long?

Comment: @wdqoihj2 the first example does just that with `long a = 'a';`

Comment: Thank you very much how it would be, when we would have a array? In this aspect it would also be a integer before it would be a long?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I gave two example of what can possibly happen. If you assign an immediate value directly to a long it gets loaded directly as a long. If you declare an integer beforehand and *then* assign its value to a long, the compiler won't (always) know how you're gonna use that integer, so it declares it as an integer and when you assign it to a long it just stores it in the long. Also consider that the language specification doesn't seem to indicate *how* a widening conversion should be compiled to bytecode and the compiler may optimize things away anyway.

Comment: Okay thank you but how I could make for example directly a char variable to a long without that that would be a int before? SO for example char[] asd={'F','A'}, do we have any way to convert this directly to long, without the step that the value would be a integer?

Comment: @wdqoihj2 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html This the link to the instruction set. Other than coding it differently, I don't see a way that you could do that.

Comment: @wdqoihj2 unless you plan to manually write the bytecode, I don't think the language supports something like that. If you want a long declare a long (`long[] asd = {'F','A'}`). The moment you declared it as something else you told the compiler you wanted... something else :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think the source of confusion for the OP (OP please correct me if I am wrong) is that it appears that Java COULD support this, but it doesn't. I am sure there is a reason why it doesn't and I think it has to do with registers. Whatever the reason, it doesn't appear to be clear.

Answer (score -1):

Long is 64 bit.

When you assign an int value to a long variable, the value is converted to long.

```
        long a = 5;  // same as long a = (long) 5;
        long b = 5L;
```

Comment: The OP already knows this. OP wants to know if the conversion is made directly to 64-bits or if the conversion is made intermediately to a 32-bit answer and then to 64.